# Is there a specific name for the type of bridge that signals that a song is going from one key to another

Tags: key

The music starts in C and then there is a BRIDGE of some type that is played and the ear is prepared for the fact that the music is going to another key.

What is this "we are shifting to another key"bridge called?

Comment: When should that transition take place? WIthin the bridge, directly after it or even later?

Comment: Directly after it.

Answer (score 2):

I don't study popular music all that often, but in other genres, we would just qualify this with an adjective that suggests it modulates. We have a few ways of saying this in our toolbox:

- Modulating bridge
- Modulatory bridge
- Progressive bridge

I don't know if there's an official term for this, but if there isn't, I think any educated musician would know what you mean if you used one of the above terms.

Answer (score 0):

The word "bridge" refers to a part of the song or piece of music and is often discussed in terms of the song's "structure" or musical form.  See https://tobyrush.com/theorypages/ Under the subheading "The Common Practice Period: Development & Form,"  there are a number of easy to comprehend pamphlets that should cover about this area of music theory albeit with reference to log-dead composers.

If the music changes key centre that would be called "modulation" Here Toby Rush covers modulation on a pamphlet called, "Diatonic Common Chord Modulation" Toby explains the jargon.

Comment: Thanks, Emma.  This was exactly what I needed.